# Etale groupoid and Morita equivalence

Tags: category-theory, groupoids, orbifolds

Let $\mathcal{G}=(G_{1}\rightrightarrows G_0)$ be a groupoid, where $G_{0}$ is the space of objects and $G_{1}$ is the space of morphisms. $\mathcal{G}$ is called etale if both the source and target maps
$$
s,t:G_{1}\rightarrow G_{0}
$$
are local diffeomorphisms. Being etale is $not$ invariant under Morita equivalence (equivalence of categories).

Could anyone give me a simple example of this fact?

Answer (score 2):

Take the action of $R$ on itself. The associated groupoid is the equivalence relation.
This is Morita equivalent to a point (the action is free and proper). $R\times R$ is not etale.

A better example would be to look at the full holonomy groupoid vs the restriction to a complete transversal.